# The power series sinh(x) around x=ln(2)

Tags: power-series

I want to find the series of Sinh(x) around x=ln(2)
.
I solved it using 2 different method .

First method:
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}=\frac{e^{(x-\ln(2))+\ln(2)}-e^{-(x-\ln(2))-\ln(2)}}{2}=e^{(x-\ln(2)}-0.25e^{-(x-\ln(2))}$$
hence

$$\sinh(x)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(x-\ln(2))^n}{n!}-0.25\frac{(-1)^n(x-\ln(2))^n}{n!}=\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}[1+0.25(-1)^{n-1}](x-\ln(2))^n$$
Second method :
$$\sinh(x)=\sinh((x-\ln(2))+\ln(2))=\sinh(x-\ln(2))\cosh(\ln(2))+\sinh(\ln(2))\cosh(x-\ln(2))$$
$$\sinh(x)=\sinh((x-\ln(2))+\ln(2))=\frac{5}{4}\sinh(x-\ln(2))+\frac{3}{4}\cosh(x-\ln(2))$$
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{5}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x-\ln(2))^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x-ln(2))^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

#### My question is :

I want to apply some operations on the solution of the second method to have the same form of the solution gotten from first method.
How can I deal with ($2n$) and ($2n+1$) in the summation?
Can I just make some substitutions? for example : $m=2n+1$ and $r=2n$? as following?
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{5}{4}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(x-\ln(2))^{m}}{m!}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{(x-\ln(2))^{r}}{r!}$$
(I think no because when I computed some terms, I found it is wrong! But how can I deal with this!?)

Comment: Use identities:$$\sinh(a+b)=\sinh(a)\cosh(b)+\cosh(a)\sinh(b)$$

Comment: Or exponential identities:$$e^{-(x-\ln(2))}=2\cdot e^{-x}$$